# auto resize column width to fit content in a dialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

[image: Screenshot of wizard dialog]

I want to resize column width automatically to match the longest content width. And I have made a function (`ResizeColumnWidth`) to do this job. However, it seems that the function did't work after adding contents longer than header. Once I click Back or Next button and return this dialog again, it will resize the column width automatically. Did I miss any step after calling resizing function when adding the contents in the field? Or did I called that function in a wrong place?

Here is my code:

```
void CWzdEventDependencies::ResizeColumnWidths()
{
    SetRedraw(FALSE);

    m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(0, 100);
    int nHeaderWidth = m_lstDependencies.GetColumnWidth(0);
    m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(0, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE);
    int nColumnWidth = m_lstDependencies.GetColumnWidth(0);
    m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(0, max(nColumnWidth, nHeaderWidth));

    m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(1, 95);

    m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(2, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
    nHeaderWidth = m_lstDependencies.GetColumnWidth(2);
    m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(2, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE);
    nColumnWidth = m_lstDependencies.GetColumnWidth(2);
    m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(2, max(nColumnWidth, nHeaderWidth));
    m_lstDependencies.SortColumn(0);
    SetRedraw(TRUE);

//  m_lstDependencies.SetColumnWidth(0, 50);

}

    enter code here

void CWzdEventDependencies::InsertDependencies()
{
    m_lstDependencies.DeleteAllItems();
    CorrelationData::FieldsDependenciesType::const_iterator It = m_pFieldsDependencies->begin();
    int nDependency = 0;
    for(; It != m_pFieldsDependencies->end(); ++It, ++nDependency)
    {
        InsertDependency(*It);
    }
}

int CWzdEventDependencies::InsertDependency(const CorrelationEventFieldDependencies* pDependency)
{
    AString strField1    = pDependency->GetField1();
    AString strOperation = pDependency->GetOperation();
    AString strField2    = pDependency->GetField2();

    LVITEM lvItem = {0};

    lvItem.mask         = LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_PARAM;
    lvItem.iItem        = m_lstDependencies.GetItemCount();
    lvItem.pszText      = strField1.LockBuffer();
    lvItem.lParam       = (LPARAM) pDependency;

    lvItem.iItem = m_lstDependencies.InsertItem(&lvItem, m_pCmbFields);
    strField1.UnlockBuffer();
    ASSERT(lvItem.iItem != -1);

    lvItem.pszText      = strOperation.LockBuffer();
    lvItem.iSubItem = 1;
    m_lstDependencies.SetItem(&lvItem, m_pCmbSign);
    strOperation.UnlockBuffer();

    lvItem.pszText      = strField2.LockBuffer();
    lvItem.iSubItem = 2;
    m_lstDependencies.SetItem(&lvItem, m_pCmbFields);
    strField2.UnlockBuffer();

    ResizeColumnWidths();
    UpdateWindow();

    return lvItem.iItem;
}
```

Comment: I have some very similar code in an old app, and it works. I call it in the OnInitialUpdate() function. Your code seems OK to me. Maybe try invalidating the listview control instead of calling UpdateWindow()?

Comment: UpdateWindow() is just one function helpless now. In my code, the ResizeColumnWidths() cannot work well called by InsertDependency() because there is no content insert now, and I got a function named AddDependency() callling InsertDependency(). But if I call ResizeColumnWidths() in at the end of AddDependency(), program will crash. I an wandering how to get the effect of auto-resizing column after selecting an event filed in dialog. Sir, Could you tell me which step calls OnInitialUpdate() in you old app. Or  OnInitialUpdate() is just an initial function for app?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Going back and forth in Wizard window should not cause a resize. Show the rest of the code.